# how can I present a network diagram on the building that has 3 floors

Tags: networking, vlan, network-design

How can I present a network diagram on the building that has 3 floors? The requirements are to separate the users in one LAN according to their department, what confuses me is on the second and on the Ground floor has Admin staff, what I have is.. in every floor have their on own switch as a Distribution.

This is what I've got so far:

[image]

Comment: VLANs to the rescue. as for your diagram, I'd recommend coloring segments based on their vlan/department.

Comment: Often with network diagrams, problems arise when you try to attempt to do a logical and physical design in a single diagram.  It is usually easier to both create and read a network layout where these are two separate diagrams.  Do one diagram with your vlan setup with the departmental separation, and another with your hardware setup across the floors.

Comment: Have you never seen a Hollywood movie? You have to create a 3D rotating green-on-black wireframe model of the building and ensure all staff are represented by flashing red dots.

Comment: @Paul Could you post that as an answer please? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Often with network diagrams, problems arise when you try to attempt to do a logical and physical design in a single diagram.

It is usually easier to both create and read a network layout where these are two separate diagrams.

You could  one diagram with your vlan setup with the departmental separation, and another with your hardware setup across the floors.

Sometimes, once you have done this, you'll see a way that you can combine the two in a way that is still interpretable, but don't force it.